# Dynamic image manipulation service

Tags: python, image-processing, web, gimp, gimpfu

I need advise. I want to create web page, where users can upload their images, and on server side I want to put these images to prepared image template and show on page. Is it possible? Is it possible with GIMP scripting? Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean with prepare image template? Give an example. What would could someone do on that page.

Comment: @Piglet For example as template: white t-shirt image. And user uploads own photo, and on server side I will put user's photo on t-shirt and return to user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want something that exists only in some Gimp script/plugin (and even then, most of them are open-source...) using Gimp for non-interactive work is at best overkill and very often more complicated than strictly necessary.

Simple (and even fairly complicated) programmed image edits can be done with several libraries and utilities. [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a nice toolbox to do image editing in shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

A Imagemagick user has some code to put an image on a T shirt on his website: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tshirt/index.php
It is a script but you should be able to call it from a web page.

He has some code for clyinders as well and I used it to put labels onto bottles and mugs.

**Note if you use his code commercially you should pay for it.**